# How to generate/find TPC workloads traces

Tags: performance, memory-management, benchmarking, simulate, oltp

I'm trying to evaluate a particular cache design on my own simulator. I need traces of read and write operations. I found out that TPC workloads are memory stressful and I'd like to use them for my design evaluation. I was wondering if the traces are available or I need to run them on particular system and configuration and generate the traces myself?

I noticed that the original [TPC website](http://www.tpc.org/default.asp) has links to download tools and scripts to run. But I'm looking to see if the traces with memory operation details are already available for architectural research purposes. If not what is the best way to generate them?

Any information would be appreciated.